# Unable to inject controller to Karma test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I have spent hours trying to set up unit testing on an existing angularjs code base. I believe I have pinned the issue down to a single oddity in our code compared to the suggested implementation from angular's docs.

We instantiate our module with `var app= angular.module(...)` whereas examples I have found use `angular.module(...)`. Would this require me to reference the module differently in the `beforeEach` shown below?

Version Details:

- AngularJS v1.2.7
- Angular-Mocks v1.2.7

myController.js:

```
app.controller('myController', function (
  $scope,
  $rootScope,
  $location,
  $window,
  globalServices,
  $routeParams,
  $sce) {
  ...
}
```

Sample.spec.js:

```
describe('myController', function() {

  beforeEach(module('app'));  

  describe('tests', function() {
    var scope, controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
      scope = {};
      controller = $controller('myController', { $scope: scope });
    }));    

    it('should define controller', function() {
      expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });

  });
});
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.tinymce',
    'ngResource',
    'ngCookies',
    ...
]);
```

karma.conf.js:

```
//jshint strict: false
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: './',

    files: [  
      'Scripts/angular.min.js',
      'Scripts/angular-mocks.js',       
      'Scripts/angular-route.min.js',
      'Scripts/angular-resource.js',
      'Scripts/angular-cookies.min.js',
      'Scripts/ui-sortable.js',
      'Scripts/angular-strap.min.js',    
      'Scripts/jquery.min.js',
      'tinymce/tinymce.min.js',      
      'Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js',
      'tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js',
      'app/directives/adapt/adapt.js',
      'app/app.js',
      'app/controllers/myController.js',
      'app/tests/Sample.spec.js'      
    ],

    autoWatch: true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-junit-reporter',
      'phantomjs-polyfill'
    ],

    reporters: ['progress']

  });
};
```

I receive the following error:
`Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error`
`Failed to instantiate module app due to:
{1}`

If I comment out the controller code, the `module('app')` will not throw an error.

Thank you very much for the help. I have hit a wall with this one.

Comment: I can't see how you create your module would make a difference. Let me look at it a wee bit longer. Are you getting some sort of error message?

Comment: a better way would be to use `beforeEach`

Comment: could you also show us your controller code?

Comment: I agree about the beforeEach, create your controller in a before each, instead of at the test level.

Comment: The error I am receiving is: `Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error` `Failed to instantiate module app due to:
{1}`. I will update the question to show the controller in a `beforeEach` as suggested. I had tried this and received the same error, I posted this way as I thought it simplified the question. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the question as suggested. Still encountering the same error. Thank you!

Comment: Were you planning on showing the controller code?

Comment: I am assuming the ticketDetailController is in myController.js, I might also put all my vendor scripts above my app code.

Comment: I have added the wrapper code from my controller file. As you can see, I create the controller on `app.controller` since I define my module on `var app = angular.module(...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117019/discussion-between-ryan27-and-maccurt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all the dependencies on module is resolved, this problem occurs when you are trying to inject a service that not been loaded.

Comment: good, but how ? I checked and everything seems to be included

Comment: @M.Octavio - I wish I knew. I thought a bounty would attract some help. The only way I resolved it was to triple check everything one by one.